# Bootstrap 3 column layout drag and drop with JSON Export

Tags: javascript, json, grid, bootstrap-grid

I am new to bootstrap and JqueryUI. I wanted to do simple 3 column layout which needs to have textbox and radiobuttons inside the box and needs to have drag and drop feature. I found a good example:`Bootstrap Drag and Drop Grid`http://jsfiddle.net/vacidesign/uskx816g/ . I have tried this example but drag and drop feature is not working in my local machine. I actually wanted exact similar example with simple textbox and drag and drop feature and on click of the button those information in textbox should be exported as JSON. Please help.

[Bootstrap 3 column layout drag and drop with JSON Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8onwf.png)

[Bootstrap Fiddle Example not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SftZR.png)

My System Spec is 4 GB ram,Windows Os,Chrome Browser.
I have included all 6 libraries mentioned in that fiddle example.

Comment: This fiddle is working fine for me, can you edit your question with your system specs? (os, browser, etc...)

Comment: Updated my question